# Remove attachment from database

Tags: attachments

Is there a way to bulk remove attachments from WordPress database but not delete the actual files from the server?

Sort of like the opposite of http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a custom [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) query, something like

```
function remove_all_attachments() {
  global $wpdb;
  $ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'");
  if ( empty($ids) ) return;
  $remove = implode(',', $ids);
  // remove post meta
  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN ({$remove})");
  // remove posts
  $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = IN ({$remove})");
}
```

After that just call `remove_all_attachments()` whatever you want and all your attachemnts posts are gone, but the file stay there...

Comment: If I use the plugin SQL Executioner, I'd use `$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'");` to run command, is that correct?

Comment: How do I filter attachments named *_small.jpg?

Comment: @ayutheos I've updated the answer to remove also postmeta. regarding your questions: *(1)* I don't know that plugin. *(2)* you can add `AND guid LIKE '%_small.jpg'` to `SELECT` query, but is not very reliable because `guid` column is not reliable... a better result involve to get the *real* image url using WP API, but if you have hundreds of images it can be a serious performance problem

Comment: [SQL Executioner](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sql-executioner) is a plugin to run SQL queries from Wordpress. I have about ~300+ manually created thumbnail images that I'd like to remove from the database but not the actual file itself. I'll try out your function in my local install to test it :)